# Is it possible to further simplify $\int^{-\pi/10}_{\pi/10} 2\pi\cdot 4 \cos(5x) \cdot \sqrt{(4 \cos(5x))^2 +(-20\sin (5x))^2} \;dx$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

Is it possible to further simplify this integral?

$$S= \int^{-\pi/10}_{\pi/10} 2\pi\cdot 4 \cos(5x) \cdot \sqrt{(4 \cos(5x))^2 +(-20\sin (5x))^2} \;dx$$

Comment: First I would switch to an integral $\int_a^b$ with $a < b$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Notice that $$(4\cos(5x))^2+(-20\sin(5x))^2=(4\cos(5x))^2+(4\sin(5x))^2+(16\sin(5x))^2\\=16\cos^2(5x)+16\sin^2(5x)+16(4\sin(5x))^2\\=16(1+4\sin(5x))^2$$
Then you can change the variable $u=4\sin(5x)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: $\cos(5x)^2 + \sin(5x)^2 = 1$

Hint 2: $\cos(5x)dx = d(\sin(5x))/5$

Comment: I do not understand the second one.

Comment: In other words, if you use @Andrei's suggestion to change the variable to $u=4\sin(5x)$, then you would need $du = 20\cos(5x)dx$